# What are the steps to use AWS token vending machine from IOS (Xcode) for subscription to SNS notification?

Tags: ios, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm struggling to understand the poorly written documentation on AWS SNS service.

I am able to configure an account and suscribe it manually to the TOPIC and push notifications.

However from a security point of view Amazon say you shouldn't store the access id and secret in the application.

https://aws.amazon.com/articles/Mobile/4611615499399490

But their documentation doesn't explain to you with any code samples as to what steps you need to take to get this up and running. The code samples in the SDK don't seem to match the current SDK framework 6.1

So I am at a loss at to which parts of the framework i should implement.

Has anyone got any code samples that they can share to help here?

Comment: I am one of the maintainers of the AWS SDK for iOS.  I'm sorry you're experiencing issues.  The SDK was written with a base level of iOS 4.3 for support, but should be compatible with devices running the latest version of iOS.

Could you clarify what it is you're looking for?  You should be able to start with the TVM samples located in our [samples repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) and update the policies in the TVM to meet your use case.

Comment: Sorry if this is a basic question but I feel like I've read all your documentation and am going round in circles. As there are not implementation steps.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry for the confusion.  Our recommended solutions for delivering session credentials are either the Token Vending Machine (which you referenced in your question) or web identity federation.

For the TVM, as I mentioned in a comment, you should refer to the [iOS samples repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) for implementation details.  The samples include Objective-C code to interface with the two different sample implementations of the TVM, [anonymous](http://aws.amazon.com/code/8872061742402990) and [identity](http://aws.amazon.com/code/7351543942956566).  Included with the TVM implementations will be instructions for setting up and deploying them in Elastic Beanstalk.

For web identity federation, you can checkout out our [S3 personal file store sample](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4617974389850313) which is included with the SDK.  This sample has instructions for configuring all three supported identity providers (Facebook, Google, and Amazon).

If you want more information about web identity federation, here are a number of other informational pages:

- [Adding Web Identity Federation with Facebook to iOS Projects](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1P67OUG61P9CB/Adding-Web-Identity-Federation-with-Facebook-to-iOS-Projects)
- [Adding Web Identity Federation with Facebook to Android Projects](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx15RSS024YGKUL/Adding-Web-Identity-Federation-with-Facebook-to-Android-Projects)
- [Creating Temporary Security Credentials for Mobile Apps Using Identity Providers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/CreatingWIF.html)
- [Web Identity Federation Playground](https://web-identity-federation-playground.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

Once you have one of these two solutions configured, it should be a simple matter of modifying the policies applied to your session credentials to limit to the functionality you desire.

Comment: Was wondering why can't AWS provide the TVM as a service on it's own. Why is a separate EC2 instance required to host the TVM? Unless I am reading the documents wrongly, but it appears that if I just want a vanilla setup, all I need to do is to conjure up a ElasticBean to host the vanilla Java WAR file. After that I will also need to configure and upload the policy json via some web interface?